# how to call web api method in mobile jquery

Tags: jquery, cordova

I have ASP.Net MVC 4 Web API project. In this project's controller I have created all methods with a return type of `HttpResponseMessage`. The following is the code of my Web API controller.

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage RegisterNewUser(string UserName, string                    AuthToken)
{
    JsonResult objJR = new JsonResult();
    JUser objJU = new JUser();
    HttpResponseMessage response;
    try
    {
        response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.ExpectationFailed,              objJR);
        return response;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return CatchError(e.Message);
    }
}

[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage GetUserProfile(int UserID, string AuthToken)
{
    JsonResult objJR = new JsonResult();
    JUser objJU = new JUser();
    HttpResponseMessage response;
    BCUsers objBCUsers = new BCUsers();
    try
    {
        response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, ds);
    }
    return response;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return CatchError(e.Message);
    }
}
```

Then I have created mobile app in phonegap, from js file I'm trying to call web API method, following is the code for that

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var CommonURL = "http://localhost/api/common/";

    function GetCoachProfile(UserID,AT) {
        alert('2');
        alert(UserID + AT);
        $.ajax({
            url:  CommonURL + 'GetUserProfile?UserID=' + UserID + '&AuthToken=' + AT,
            type: 'GET',
            datatype: 'json',
            contenttype: "application/json",
            success: function (data) {
                alert('3');
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function(xhr,textStatus,errorThrown) {           
                alert(xhr.responseText);
                alert(textStatus);
                alert(errorThrown);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

The `GetCoachProfile` function gets called on button click of HTML Page, my debug point placed at web API method also gets hit after clicking button, all in web API method executed successfully still after returning in AJAX call it executes error loop and not success, please if any one help me out, I'm new to phonegap and jQuery.

Comment: You appear to have a syntax error in your C# code - the `return` statement is outside the try/catch in the `GetUserProfile` method.

Comment: Adding to above comment, JS is case-sensitive language `dataType` and `contentType`

Comment: What are these alerts showing: `alert(xhr.responseText);       alert(textStatus); alert(errorThrown);`?

Comment: alert(xhr.responseText); is showing blank, alert(textStatus); is ahowing error, alert(errorThrown); is showing blank, in web api there is not a single error, still in s ajax call executes error loop.

Comment: Issue got resolved by adding following in web.config of my api project<system.webServer><httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol></system.webServer>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved by adding following line of code in web.config file of my web api project, the issue is due to cross platform.

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol> 
      <customHeaders> 
           <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" /> 
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```